# How to change the text of a JLabel in a while loop

Tags: java, swing, clock, jlabel

I want to make a clock That changes the text of JLabel and i am having trouble with getting the text to change.

Thanks Obiedog!!!!

Heres my code for the clock if that helps

Comment: What is triggering actionPerformed?

Comment: Sorry about delayed answer Just a JButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29) may help you.

JLabel.setText().

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code didn't make it into the post, but I have a feeling I know what's wrong by the way you phrased your question :-)

Swing uses a single-threaded event loop to do its magic.  Things like action events get called on this thread, as well as things like painting.

If you are using a simple while loop to act as your clock delay, you'll tie up the EDT (event dispatching thread), such that Swing will never have a chance to repaint your screen!  You might even notice that dragging the window off-screen may blank it out entirely.

The solution is to use a delay mechanism that works within the event system.  Luckily, such a thing exists!  Take a look at the javax.swing.Timer (note: there are other classes called Timer, but this one is the only one that works within the event system.)  By calling setText on your JLabel (and possibly repaint) in the actionListener of that Timer, you can get clock-like behavior.